# OpenSSL encrypts public key after conversion to pfx

Tags: encryption, certificate, openssl

I'm exporting a certificate and private key into `.pfx` file with:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out export.pfx -in public.crt -inkey private.key -nodes
```

However despite encrypting private key with provided password, OpenSSL also encrypts a public key, which makes it unable to read public key header (like C, O, CN fields) by third party software without providing a password: [image: Example of encrypted public key]

How can I export it to `pfx` without encrypting public key? I want to be able to read public key headers like this: [image: Unencrypted public key]

Comment: What software are you using for the ASN.1 tree?

Comment: [ASN.1 Editor](https://www.pkisolutions.com/tools/asn1editor/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before migration(!) this was nearly a dupe of https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/195080/how-to-convert-my-cert-chain-to-pfx-without-a-password/

Aside: the body of your question says certificate, which is correct, but your title says public key, which is different and at best highly misleading.

OpenSSL can create a PKCS12 aka PFX with the 'cert bag' unencrypted using the undocumented option value `-certpbe NONE`:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -certpbe NONE -out key.pfx
```

PS: `-nodes` is only used in the *other* direction (importing) to not encrypt the extracted privatekey (if any). For `-export` it is ignored and the encryption is controlled separately by `-keypbe` and `-certpbe`.

Comment: this might even help against brute force attacks: by default the same password is used for both, but the default algorithm isn't the same: rc2-40 for the cert and 3des for the key (which isn't great to start with): https://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=543 . [Cracking the rc2-40](https://github.com/SaschaWessel/rc2-40-cbc#brute-force) might help crack the 3des.

Comment: A.B: no, breaking the rc2-40 cert encryption, which is indeed easy, should not help breaking the 3des (or other) key encryption; they use separate salts that should differ with (at least) overwhelming probability, therefore different and unrelated keys (and IVs). And the latter _can_ (but rarely does) use PBES2 which also has a different KDF.

Comment: ok. For some wrong reason I thought this gave the original password, but it's the key, not the password.